# .htaccess redirect non-www to www with subfolder masking and SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to do the following: Redirect all non-www and non-https traffic to `https://www`. Version of my website. I also have the website content in a subfolder called `/web-site/web/` and want to mask this folder. Here's what I have at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web-site/web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web-site/web/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Why are you checking the requested hostname in that rule? Are you hosting multiple domains? Have you tried to implement a canonical redirect? Is there a specific problem you are having?

Comment: @MrWhite yes, we have multiple domains on this page, that's why I'm checking the domain. As the reverse proxy doesn't allow specific Domain Roots, we have to do this via htaccess ...